# How to implement Index and Row function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write the following in VBA:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B$4:B$15;(ROW(A1)-1)/730+1)
```

I m trying:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction

 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Some_Sheet").Range("H6") = .Index(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B15")), (Range("A1").Row - 1) / 730 + 1)    

End With
```

Comment: Refer to [Range.Row Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-row-property-excel) and you can refer to relative `Range` or `Cells` to retrieve the value. Or look at [Range.Value Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Are you looking for something like `ActiveCell.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B$4:B$15"), (Range("A1").Row - 1) / 730 + 1)`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")`.   `Row(A1)-1` will always return 0.  `0/730+1=1`  So `INDEX(Range("B4:B15"),1)` will always be B4.  Edit:  Once you've dragged down 730 rows the it will start looking at B5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ActiveCell.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B$4:B$15"), (Range("A1").Row - 1) / 730 + 1)`

Comment: @DinoC, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DinoC, you can use it in a `With....End With` block. But in your edit above, you need to remove the extra `)` after `.Range("B4:B15")`, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the reference to A1 supposed to be relative to the target cell - so do you want the same value returned for rows 1-730, 731-1460, etc?

If that's the case, then something like:

```
Function foo(ByRef c As Range)
    With c
        .Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Offset(Int(.Row / 730), 0).Value
    End With
End Function
```

Used like:

```
Sub test()
    foo Worksheets("Some_Sheet").Range("H1463")
End Sub
```